# Upgrade Ruby 2.4.2 to 2.6.3 causing errors with JSON

Tags: json, ruby

I am new and searched a lot but I couldn’t find an answer to my problem.

When I upgraded my ruby projects version from `2.4.2` to `2.6.3`, my JSON gem by default upgraded from `1.8.6` to `2.1.0`.

This following codes caused errors:

```
JSON.parse("")
```

> JSON::ParserError:A JSON text must at least contain two octets!

and

```
JSON.parse("null")
```

> JSON::ParserError: 784: unexpected token at 'null’

How can I turn off/change the automatically upgrade of JSON gem or solve the above errors.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What JSON input used to work, and is now failing? Where is your code? (Just `JSON.parse`, or something more?) As it stands, I have no idea how to reproduce your problem - and therefore no idea how to answer the question.

Comment: I **suspect** (!!) that the problem has got nothing to do with the `json` gem. It's far more likely, I think, that the behaviour of the thing which generates JSON has changed... For example, maybe you're calling an API that's stopped working as expected.

Comment: @TomLord
Thank you for your comment. 
This is an example that is failing:

`JSON.parse("null")`

Also: 

JSON.parse(''")

Comment: Your original question included unicode characters (\u201C) and (\u201D) which would be unparsable by JSON. Please feel free to revoke my edit but this is what caused the error on the second example and the first example has no content so I am not sure what you expected the result to be but an empty string has always resulted in `unexpected token at ''` I cannot even recreate the error you provided in any version

Comment: Your first example is not legal JSON, so *of course* it is rejected by the JSON parser. The JSON parser only parses JSON, your first example is not JSON, ergo, the JSON parser doesn't parse it.

Comment: What command(s) did you use to update your projects? `JSON.parse('')` appears to fail in both 1.8.6 & 2.1.0. parsing `null` fails in 1.8.6, but passes in 2.1.0, so I'm in agreement with @TomLord that it's likely something else that got upgraded if you used `bundle update`, for example